# PHP5: dns_get_record() only returning A records for subdomains

Tags: php, dns, soa

Running PHP 5.2 on Linux, I am running a series of queries with `dns_get_record()`. It would appear from the documentation that this function replicates `dig` but I am seeing inconsistencies.  My goal is to get the primary and secondary nameservers that are authoritative for the domains that each hostname belongs to.

`dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_NS);` returns good results.
`dns_get_record('www.example.com', DNS_NS);` returns nothing.
`dns_get_record('www.example.com', DNS_ANY);` returns only an A-record.
`dns_get_record('www.example.com', DNS_SOA);` returns nothing.

However, from a command line using dig, I can always get at least the SOA:

`dig www.example.com NS`
or
`dig www.example.com SOA`

return a valid AUTHORITY SECTION (IN SOA) containing the nameservers.

How can I replicate this in PHP? I have tried the PEAR Net_DNS module and seen similar shenanigans as with `dns_get_record()`.

Comment: How do you know that `dig` isn't just stripping off the `www.` before doing the NS or SOA queries?

Comment: I suppose I don't know that it's not.

Comment: Sean Bright is (almost) correct. Use the option "+trace" with dig to see what is really happening:
Dig will go from the top hierarchy and work its way down (not the other way around) - usually you don't set up a SOA under the subdomain "www".
PHP's dns_get_record is _not_ dig, it will just do what you tell him to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you `dig` from the command line you're much more directly (relatively) connecting to the DNS. The output is also formatted for that scenario. When executing the php function, it returns the values its authors thought would be wanted. Doesn't necessarily directly correspond to `dig`.

If you want to get a `dig` result then you could use `exec('dig www.example.com ns');` and parse that return output as you want.

Also, if you're querying the DNS for a subdomain, i.e. www. rather than the [tld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (example.com), then you're not going to get the other records associated with it - you're ONLY going to get the results associated with that subdomain, which in your case is just an A record.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, for the node (or subdomain) you need to be more specific and know the text of the DNS entry you are requesting.

e.g. a DMARC DNS entry is a TXT entry, as is SPF and DKIM.

```
$showResult = dns_get_record('_dmarc.domain.com', DNS_TXT); //returns an array
```

works fine.